# Cannot access data in JSON array nested in JSON object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JSON information. It is an array nested inside an object. I am trying to access components of the object, however  I cant seem to figure out how to work with the object.

For instance, when I try to get the number of events in the array (there should be 2), 
`jsonObject.length` returns the character count.  where as `jsonObject[0].length` returns one, which in my opinion should be 2 (2 events).

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "eventName": "Rey",
        "name": "Tar",
        "dateOfShow": "2017-01-27T22:00:00",
        "userGroupName": "Bit",
        "eventHallName": "Grnn",
        "imageSource": "test2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "eventName": "Gor",
        "name": "Skum",
        "dateOfShow": "2017-01-30T20:00:00",
        "userGroupName": "Gaf",
        "eventHallName": "Gai",
        "imageSource": "test1.jpg"
    }
]
}
```

I have worked with JSON arrays before by parsing them, however when I parse this, it returns undefined for any value.

How would I get the number of events displayed in this JSON object using javascript?

Comment: try `jsonObject.results.length`

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this.

JSON is string.Directly javascript's `length` property will not works.You have  convert it to object first using `JSON.parse()`.

```js
json ='{"results":[{"eventName":"Rey","name":"Tar","dateOfShow":"2017-01-27T22:00:00","userGroupName":"Bit","eventHallName":"Grnn","imageSource":"test2.jpg"},{"eventName":"Gor","name":"Skum","dateOfShow":"2017-01-30T20:00:00","userGroupName":"Gaf","eventHallName":"Gai","imageSource":"test1.jpg"}]}';
res = JSON.parse(json)
alert(res.results.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse(jsonObject);` and then try to access. `json.results` it will give you the array of length two.

```
var jsonString = '{"results":[{"eventName":"Rey","name":"Tar","dateOfShow":"2017-01-27T22:00:00","userGroupName":"Bit","eventHallName":"Grnn","imageSource":"test2.jpg"},{"eventName":"Gor","name":"Skum","dateOfShow":"2017-01-30T20:00:00","userGroupName":"Gaf","eventHallName":"Gai","imageSource":"test1.jpg"}]}';
var jsonObject = JSON.parse (jsonString);
jsonObject.results.length; // length of results array
jsonObject.results[0]; //first object of array
```

Answer (score 0):

I think,this will helps you

```
  json ='{"results":[{"eventName":"Rey","name":"Tar","dateOfShow":"2017-01-27T22:00:00","userGroupName":"Bit","eventHallName":"Grnn","imageSource":"test2.jpg"},{"eventName":"Gor","name":"Skum","dateOfShow":"2017-01-30T20:00:00","userGroupName":"Gaf","eventHallName":"Gai","imageSource":"test1.jpg"}]}';
res = JSON.parse(json)
alert(res.results.length);
var i = 0;
while(i<res.results.length)
{
    alert(res.results[i].eventName)
    i++;
}
```